# Looped Equation on different subset of data R

Tags: r, loops, subset

I am trying to set up an earning pattern on some data. I'm doing this by creating an 'Earned_Multiplier' variable which I can then use to multiply on whatever other variable necessary later on. Where the 'Earned_Duration' is >0 and <= 30, the Earned_Multiplier should be equal to ((Earned_Duration/30)*0.347), where the 'Earned_Duration' is >30 and <=60, the Earned_Multiplier should be equal to (0.347+((Earned_Duration/30)*0.16)), and so on.

I'm hoping the below should make sense given the above description. Unfortunately I am getting the error message "NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments". I feel like this is likely because I need to be using a loop to do the calculation?

Could anyone help direct me as to how to build this loop and making sure it does the right calculation for each different subset?

```
Output_All$Earned_Multiplier <- 1
Output_All$Earned_Multiplier[Output_All$Earned_Duration == 0] <- 0
Output_All$Earned_Multiplier[(Output_All$Earned_Duration > 0) & 
(Output_All$Earned_Duration <= 30)] <- 0+ 
((Output_All$Earned_Duration/30)*.347) # Month 1
Output_All$Earned_Multiplier[(Output_All$Earned_Duration > 30) & 
(Output_All$Earned_Duration <= 60)] <- .347+(((Output_All$Earned_Duration- 
30)/30)*.16) # Month 2
Output_All$Earned_Multiplier[(Output_All$Earned_Duration > 60) & 
(Output_All$Earned_Duration <= 90)] <- .507+(((Output_All$Earned_Duration- 
60)/30)*.085) # Month 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to provide a dummy dataset so we could work on that. You probably have some NAs in your dataset causing that error. 
In any case, using the dplyr library you could do an `ifelse` statement along with a `mutate` to create a new column with your calculation result:

```
library(dplyr)
Output_All <- Output_All %>% mutate(Earned_Multiplier = ifelse(Earned_Duration == 0, 0,
                                                               ifelse(Earned_Duration>0&Earned_Duration<=30, (Earned_Duration/30)*0.347,
                                                                      ifelse(Earned_Duration>30&Earned_Duration<=60, (0.347+((Earned_Duration/30)*0.16)), #close with final else here, if none of the above is met
                                                                      ))))# or continue with more ifelse statements
```

*Regarding the NAs:*
If you do have NAs and they are causing you issues, depending on your preference, you can include this as part of your logical statements:

```
!is.na(Earned_Duration) # dont forget to add & if you add it as a condition
```

to make sure that NAs are disregarded.